# Add ng-click to all <img> in ionic project

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic2, angular-directive

im really newbie in ionic and angular, and i need to add in each img element ng-click attribute. I tried to use $compile but i always had some problems with errors, like

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

**HTML**

```
 <img src="img/VIyNbAJ8TbeAQQo6Nm3m_Pic1.PNG"  style="display: block; width: 100%; height: auto; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('modalCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $compile) {

$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/modal.html', {
    scope: $scope
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});

$scope.openModal = function (event) {
    $scope.modal.show();
    $scope.imgUrl = event.target.src;
}
```

**directives.js**

```
.directive('img', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element) {

        element.attr('ng-click', "openModal($event)" );

        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
};
```

How i can put ng-click in every img automatically? Tnx you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of compiling an `ng-click` directive, simply add a click handler:

```
app.directive('img', function ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function (scope, element) {

        //element.attr('ng-click', "openModal($event)" );
        //$compile(element)(scope);

        element.on("click", function(event) {
            scope.$eval("openModal($event)", {$event: event});
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
};
```